# How to get last inserted row in SQlite android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I want to get the last inserted row's primary key value which is set automatically(AUTO INCREMENT). I searched over the S/O and found answers for last row_id. But I need the last inserted row's values. Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: show that create table query?

Comment: What have you done till now ? Some piece of code would be much more helpful..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get generated id after insert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409751/get-generated-id-after-insert)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40962443/1770868

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this code

```java
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + "sqlite_sequence";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
cursor.moveToLast();
```

or

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM    TABLE
WHERE   ID = (SELECT MAX(ID)  FROM TABLE);
```

or

```sql
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: The second and third solutions are all you need.

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
select * from <TABLE> where row_id = (select max(row_id) from <TABLE>);
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY row_id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`moveToLast()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) in [`Cursor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) interface.

From [android.googlesource.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

```
/**
 * Move the cursor to the last row.
 *
 * <p>This method will return false if the cursor is empty.
 *
 * @return whether the move succeeded.
 */
boolean moveToLast();
```

Simple example:

```
final static String TABLE_NAME = "table_name";
String name;
//....

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);

if(cursor.moveToLast()){
    name = cursor.getString(column_index);
    //--get other cols values
}
```

If you want to get data when insert, you can use [`insert()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) in [`SQLiteDatabase` class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html).

```
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "table_name";
private static final String COLUMN_ONE = "ID";
private static final String COLUMN_TWO = "NAME";

long row = 0;//to get last row
//.....
SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();

ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put(COLUMN_TWO, name);//name is a variable for data value

row = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
//insert() returns the row ID of the newly inserted row, or -1 if an error occurred 

Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE ID = ?", new String[] { row+"" });
while (res.moveToNext()) {//there is no need to use while, if condition is good.
    System.out.println(res.getString(0));//I just sout to avoid more code.
    System.out.println(res.getString(1));
}
```

[This is post is about autoincrement, if you want to read.](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)