# Last Insert Row ID in sqlite for xamarin android

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, rowid

This is my insert in database code. How can i return the last insert rowid of after insertion? I'm using Xamarin.Android, thanks

```
public void checkDays(int medID, int mon, int tue, int wed, int thu, int fri, int sat, int sun)
        {
            try{
                sqldb_query = "INSERT INTO Days (medicationID, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday) VALUES ('" + medID + "', '" + mon + "', '" + tue + "', '" + wed + "', '" + thu + "', '" + fri + "', '" + sat + "','" + sun + "');";
                sqldb.ExecSQL(sqldb_query);
                //msg = "Record Saved";
            }catch(Android.Database.Sqlite.SQLiteException e){
                //msg = "No " + e.Message;
                throw(e);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use `SELECT last_insert_rowid();` ... Also your question might be a duplicate of a number of other SO posts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get generated id after insert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409751/get-generated-id-after-insert)

Comment: How exactly should I used it?

Comment: I've tried id = sqldb.ExecSQL(sqldb_query); But it gives me an error of Cannot implicitly convert 'void' to 'long'.