# SQLite: How to limit the number of rows based on the timestamp?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, triggers, database-trigger

I successfully used the following `BEFORE INSERT` trigger to limit the number of rows stored in the SQLite database table *locations*. The database table acts as a cache in an Android application.

```
CREATE TRIGGER 'trigger_locations_insert'
BEFORE INSERT ON 'locations'
WHEN ( SELECT count(*) FROM  'locations' ) > '100'
  BEGIN
    DELETE FROM 'locations' WHERE '_id' NOT IN
    (
      SELECT '_id' FROM 'locations' ORDER BY 'modified_at' DESC LIMIT '100' 
    );
  END
```

Meanwhile, I added a second trigger that allows me to `INSERT OR UPDATE` rows. - The discussion on that topic can be found in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686645/android-sqlite-insert-update-table-columns-to-keep-the-identifier). The second trigger requires a `VIEW` on which each `INSERT`is executed.

```
CREATE VIEW 'locations_view' AS SELECT * FROM 'locations';
```

Since an `INSERT` is no longer executed on the `TABLE` *locations* but on the `VIEW` *locations_view*, the above trigger does no longer work. If I apply the trigger on the `VIEW` the following error message is thrown.

```
Failure 1 (cannot create BEFORE trigger on view: main.locations_view)
```

**Question:**

How can I change the above trigger to observe each `INSERT` on the `VIEW` - or do you recommend another way to limit the number of rows? I would prefer to handle this kind of operation within the database, rather then running frontend code on my client.

---

**Performance issues:**

Although, the limiter (the above trigger) works in general - it performs less then optimal! Actually, the database actions take so long that an ANR is raised. As far as I can see, the reason is, that the limiter is called **every** time an `INSERT` happens. To optimize the setup, the bulk `INSERT` should be wrapped into a transaction and the limiter should perform right after. Is this possible? If you like to help, please place optimization comments concerning the bulk `INSERT` into the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686645/android-sqlite-insert-update-table-columns-to-keep-the-identifier). Comments regarding the limiter are welcome here.

Comment: you could just use code to do that instead of triggers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of trigger should work fine in conjunction with the other one.  The problem appears to be that the SQL is unnecessarily quoting the `_id` field.  It is selecting the literal string "_id" for every row and comparing that to the same literal string.

Removing the quotes around `'_id'` (both in the `DELETE` and in the sub-`SELECT`) should fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you. Strange error message, though. It works in general now, but the performance is less than good. I will add my concerns to the question.

Comment: **Anwer-Update:** I just found out: the actual problem are the **quoted limits** such as `'100'`. The quoted id `'_id'` is not the problem. Nevertheless, you pointed into the right direction.

Comment: Ah, interesting.  Good to know!