# Android: SQLite - insertWithOnConflict

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

I am calling insertWithOnConflict, using SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE. However, when a conflict occurs "-1" is returned instead of the id of the existing row. How do I correct this?

Table creation:

**EDIT :**

```
String CREATE_CATEGORY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_CATEGORY+"(" +
    BaseColumns._ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
    KEY_CATEGORY_NAME+" TEXT UNIQUE" +
    ")";
db.execSQL(CREATE_CATEGORY_TABLE);
```

Insert statement:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(KEY_CATEGORY_NAME, name);
int catID = (int) db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_CATEGORY, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
```

Comment: A return value of -1 means an error has occurred. Does it also return -1 if you insert a unique (non-conflicting) row?

Comment: @Graham Borland : No. A non conflicting insert will return the correct row id.

Answer (score 9):

insertWithOnConflict, using SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE does not work as expected and should probably be avoided altogether, as per this issue:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13045

Answer (score 2):

Android expects the primary key column to be called `_id`. Might be the cause: since the column does not exist, it can't return the value and returns -1.

Answer (score 2):

SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE comment is supposed to function the same way as you had observed. While trying to insert, if there is no conflicting row, then it will insert a new row with the given values and return the id of the newly inserted row. On the other hand if there is already a conflicting row (with same unique key), then the incoming values will be ignored and the existing row will be retained and then the return value will be -1 to indicate a conflict scenario. To know further details and to understand how to handle this return value, please read [Android/SQLite: Insert-Update table columns to keep the identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686645/android-sqlite-insert-update-table-columns-to-keep-the-identifier?lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

The workaround that I used is using `insertOrThrow` instead of `insertWithOnConflict`, and explicitly catching `SQLiteConstraintException`. You need to explicitly catch it because it inherits from `RuntimeException`.

I had to use this workaround because `insert` was dumping the database scheme to the logs when there was a conflict, and that was unacceptable.

Answer (score -1):

```
try {
        long id = db.insertWithOnConflict(StatusData.TABLE, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
        if (id == -1){
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("%s: Failed to insert [%s] to [%s] for unkwon reason.",TAG,values,uri));
        }else
            return ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri, id);
    }
```

I am still able to get the row inserted into the database, the CONFLICT_IGNORE does not work as expected @Tom is right but i am not sure if that issue was fixed