# Android Sqlite: last_insert_rowid() after insert

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to get the `last_insert_rowid()` after my insert statement.

I wanted to use `SQLiteDatabase.execSQL()` but it says that I can't use select statements there.

How can I use `last_insert_rowid()`?

Comment: Please check the below thread 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017903/get-last-inserted-value-from-sqlite-database-android

It may help you.

Comment: Also, You can use db.rawQuery("SELECT last_insert_rowid()", null), and get the value from the cursor.

Comment: @Amit tnx this is what I been looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have used this method for insert data in sqlite database its give you new inserted row.

**No need to use any another method.**

**public long insert (String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values)**

Parameters

**table**   the table to insert the row into

**nullColumnHack**  optional; may be null. SQL doesn't allow inserting a completely empty row without naming at least one column name. If your provided values is empty, no column names are known and an empty row can't be inserted. If not set to null, the nullColumnHack parameter provides the name of nullable column name to explicitly insert a NULL into in the case where your values is empty.

**values**  this map contains the initial column values for the row. The keys should be the column names and the values the column values

**It Returns
the row ID of the newly inserted row, or -1 if an error occurred**

like:

```
long a = database.insert("animals", null, values);
```

`a` is your table's row id.