# Retrieving last inserted 'n' rows from a table

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to retrieve last inserted 'n' number of rows from an SQLite table. I used the below query but I'm getting error, please help me to correct my query. If my query is wrong please suggest me a better query:

```
public Cursor readLastNDetails(int n)
{
    return this.data.rawQuery("SELECT TOP ("+n+") Name,Place,occupation,Date from  tb_Employee order by id DESC", null);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15833147/1168654

Comment: @DhawalSodha this is not i m looking for, i want to retrieve the last n records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following query,

```
"select Name,Place,occupation,Date 
 from  tb_Employee 
 order by id 
 desc limit"+ n
```

Answer (score 1):

finally i got the answer

```
public Cursor readLastNYield(int n)
{
    return this.data.rawQuery("select BatchName,Yield,ActualYield,Date from tb_LabAssessment order by id DESC limit "+n, null);
}
```