# How can I get last ID after inserting record?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, insert

Given the following code:

```
 sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table if not exists ACCOUNT (ID integer primary key autoincrement," +
                        "CASH LONG NOT NULL," +
                        "BANKID INTEGER NOT NULL," +
                        "ACCOUNTNO TEXT ," +
                        "DATE TEXT NOT NULL," +
                        "COMMENT TEXT);");
```

A table is created in SQLite.

How can I get a lastID after adding a record?

With the following code:

```
 contentValues.put("CASH", accountTO.getCash());
 contentValues.put("DATA", DatePro.currentDate());
 contentValues.put("BANKID", accountTO.getBankID());
 contentValues.put("ACCOUNTNO", accountTO.getAccountNo());
 contentValues.put("COMMENT", accountTO.getComment());

 Long i = sqLiteDatabase.insert("ACCOUNT", null, contentValues);
```

I get `-1`.

Comment: get the ID which is max

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get last inserted value from sqlite database Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017903/get-last-inserted-value-from-sqlite-database-android)

Comment: Record ID which has already been added

Comment: Column name `DATE` in `create table`, `DATA` in `contentValues`. Fix that first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public long insert (String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values)
```

*Returns
the `rowID` of the newly inserted row, or `-1` if an error occurred.*