# get Primary key rather than rowID while inserting in sqlite or get primary key by its rowID

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Is there a smart way of getting the primary key that is auto incremented rather than rowID while inserting in the database, basically i don't want to write a new query to get the primary key of the last entry, is there any way to get the primary key using its rowID.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question does not make sense; in SQLite, [the autoincremented key always is the rowid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695224/sqlite-getting-nearest-locations-with-latitude-and-longitude).

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 : If you use The Android SQLite DB class methods, they return the last inserted id.

Option 2 : SELECT last_insert_rowid();

Refer to [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017903/get-last-inserted-value-from-sqlite-database-android)

Comment: does this return me the primary key i have settled in the table ?

Comment: @ZubairAkber - I suppose you have autoincrement on your primary key .. In that case it returns the last inserted row id ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i want to get the primary key instead of rowID or is there a way to get row data by its rowID

Comment: @ZubairAkber - Then please explain what is your primary key ? Share the create SQL code of your table. 

If your primary key is NOT the auto increment integer, then it means that you are manually inserting a primary key ... 
If you are manually inserting - then you already have ...